# Boost XCode i386

Tags: xcode, boost, i386

I need to use i386 with Boost because of another SDK I'm using. I tried building Boost with

```
./b2 toolset=darwin architecture=x86 address-model=32
```

to get the 32-bit version, but it's giving me a linker error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I've also tried using

```
port install boost
```

but only get the x86_64 version of boost that way.

Is there another way to build Boost so that I can compile using i386 in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile the i386 version using macports by editing the macports config file located at

```
/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf
```

and uncommenting this line

```
build_arch  i386
```

After that I just called

```
sudo port install boost
```

and voilà, now it's working!